# What is the String 'volumeName' argument of MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri referring to?

Tags: android

I am wanting to query the members of a given playlist.  I have the correct playlist id, and want to use a managedQuery() to look at the playlist members in question.

What I have is this:

```
private String [] columns = { 
     MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAYLIST_ID,
     MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE,
     };
Uri membersUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri(volume, playlistId);
Cursor tCursor = managedQuery(membersUri, columns, null, null, null);
```

I don't know what the volume argument needs to be.  I've tried this:
`MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString()` for the "volume" argument.

That gives me back a valid content URI that looks like:

```
content://media/external/audio/playlists/2/members
```

However, my cursor comes back null.  I probably am way off base -- I know what I want to do is very simple.

Comment: I've narrowed things down -- I believe "external" is the argument I am looking for.  I figure it is since I can use any bogus string and get the same null Cursor, but with external the URI looks correct (as above, it looks like I pasted the version from when I used "external").  

Also with "external", I get a different behavior.  I get a NullPointerException when calling managedQuery, with a very unhelpful stack trace.
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:149)
at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1499)

Answer (score 9):

The String "external" works as the volume in `MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri(volume, playlistId)`

This activity prints the songs on an Android, and the playlists, and their contents.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

public class PlaylistActivity extends Activity {
    private final String [] STAR= {"*"};
    private final String TAG= "list";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.i(TAG, "All the titles");
        Uri allaudio_uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor ca= managedQuery(allaudio_uri, STAR, null,null,null);
        for(ca.moveToFirst(); !ca.isAfterLast(); ca.moveToNext()){
            if(ca.isFirst()){   // print all the fields of the first song
                for(int k= 0; k<ca.getColumnCount(); k++)
                    Log.i(TAG, "  "+ca.getColumnName(k)+"="+ca.getString(k));
            }else{              // but just the titles of the res
                Log.i(TAG, ca.getString(ca.getColumnIndex("title")));
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "--------------------------");
        Log.i(TAG, "All the playlists");
        Uri playlist_uri= MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;    
        Cursor cursor= managedQuery(playlist_uri, STAR, null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int r= 0; r<cursor.getCount(); r++, cursor.moveToNext()){
            Log.i(TAG, "-----");
            Log.i(TAG, "Playlist " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            for(int k= 0; k<cursor.getColumnCount(); k++)           
                Log.i(TAG, cursor.getColumnName(k)+"="+cursor.getString(k));

            // the members of this playlist
            int id= cursor.getInt(0);
            Uri membersUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", id);
            Cursor membersCursor = managedQuery(membersUri, STAR, null, null, null);
            membersCursor.moveToFirst();
            for(int s= 0; s<membersCursor.getCount(); s++, membersCursor.moveToNext())
                Log.i(TAG, "  "+membersCursor.getString(membersCursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
            membersCursor.close();
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. What is the volume? What are its possible values besides "external"? What is "external" referring to - is it the same as the "external" used in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html? Etc.

Comment: @hexatron what is the constant value for string 'external'? I am searching for something like `const val VOLUME_EXTERNAL = "external"` declared somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code in android.provider.MediaStore, it can be either "internal" or "external"

```html
/**
 * The content:// style URI for the internal storage.
 */
public static final Uri INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI =
        getContentUri("internal");

/**
 * The content:// style URI for the "primary" external storage
 * volume.
 */
public static final Uri EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI =
        getContentUri("external");
```