# Delete picture taken from camera gets corrupted

Tags: android

I have a small app that calls the intent of image_capture from android, takes and then deletes it from the gallery.

Well, the picture is not deleted, well, not completely, the best result that I get it's this:
[image]

My code is simple, based on what I found around internet:

```
success = new File(imageUrl).delete();
//deleteFile(imageUrl);
if(success)
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The image is still registered with the media library see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379690/androids-media-scanner-how-do-i-remove-files

Comment: the selected solution there still gets the same: corrupted file.

Comment: Try the other answers maybe.

Comment: sure... I'm still looking for the solution. I tried also this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300137/how-can-i-refresh-mediastore-on-android
but, still the same!